# How to achieve (05 Jan 2017) date fromat

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and trying to get date from database in the requested format.

I am trying this query to achieve the result.

```
select * 
from datetable
```

Comment: did you even attempt to research this problem. there are numerous similar questions on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use convert function to get required result.

```
select convert(varchar,getdate(),106)
```

Result:

```
06 Jan 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Format()

```
Select Format(somedate,'dd MMM yyyy')
```

Comment: worth noting this is 2012+ as OP didn't specify version.

Comment: @Tanner Fair enough, but it is generally assumed the SQL Server tag is for currently supported versions which is 2012+.  That said, I've been surprised numerous times.

Comment: You know what they say about assumptions... :-)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti 2008 & 2008R2 are under Extended Support for 2 more years

Comment: @alroc Huh.  Good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your datatype is `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` then you can use [`CONVERT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATECOLUMN, 106)
FROM DateTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,Convert(varchar,DateColumn,106) as NewDate  from datetable
```